# Phonegap / Cordova / HTML5 Create a CSV File to download

Tags: html, cordova, csv

I need a little bit of help.
My question is: What is the right way to create a csv(/txt) file in a AndroidApp based on PhoneGap with Cordova and Javascript?

I am playing now a few days with phonegap and im really new in this direction. Now i have seen that since a few weeks the cordova-plugins are not supported anymore. (e.g.) And so im wondering how i can create/generate a csv with my app and provide it do be downloadable to the user?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean that cordova-plugins are not supported anymore?
Naturally you need to use [cordova-plugin-file](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html)

Below is simple code snippet of how to do read/write operations on files with this plugin installed.

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function (dir) {
    dir.getFile('test.txt', {create: true}, function (fileEntry) {

        fileEntry.file(function (file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onloadend = function () {
                // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (ver.json).
                fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {

                    fileWriter.onwriteend = function (e) {
                        writeCompleted = true;
                        //console.log('Write completed.');
                    };

                    fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
                        writeError = true;
                        //console.log('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
                    };

                    // Create a new Blob and write it to ver.json
                    var blob = new Blob(['foo;bar;baz'], {type: 'text/csv'});

                    fileWriter.write(blob);

                }, fileErrorHandler);

            };

            reader.readAsText(file);

        }, function () {
            console.log('onErrorReadFile');
        });


    }, fileErrorHandler);            
});
```

After you created file in filesystem you can serve for download with simple `<a>` tag.

Comment: how to use above code to download the file can you help me?

Comment: to download a file you need to use [cordova-plugin-file-transfer](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/index.html)